# Undefined on calling getter to get item by id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

resident.js

```
state : {
    residents: []
},
getters:{
  getResidentsById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.residents.find(resident => resident.id === id)
 }
```

}

Medication.vue

```
data() {
   return { medications: [],
},
computed: {
   ...mapGetters([
        'allMedications',  //this returns all the list of medication
        'getResidentsById',
    ]),
 },
 method: {
    getResidentName(id) {
      const resident = this.getResidentsById(id)
      return resident && resident.name
    },
 },
 watch: {
    allMedications() {
      const medicationArray = this.allMedications
      this.medications = medicationArray.map(medication => 
    ({
        ...medication,
        residentName: this.getResidentName(medication.resident)
    })
    );
    },
 }
```

I wanted to set **residentName** prop in **medications** list by passing **resident id** from medication. I am getting **undefined** on calling **getResidentsById**. Medication object contains resident key whose value is id of resident.

Comment: The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned. - proof list contains item, else it behaves as expected

Comment: @Estradiaz both of the list contains items. But still I am getting undefined.

Comment: @user12140833 Maybe it's a type of `id` problem. You can try with the double equals to see if your getter passes: `return state.residents.find(resident => resident.id == id)`

Comment: In your code example above `residents` is an empty list. To expect something to exist is not a proof - maybe its an issue with how you fill the list, but my glas ball broke :( so it is very appreciated to show that the list is not empty e.g. how you fill it :) - else `undefined` is expected

Answer (score 1):

```
// residents.js

import Vue from 'vue'

const state = {
    residents: {}
}

const mutations = {
    RESIDENT_ADD (state, value) {
        Vue.set(state.residents, value.residentId, value)
    }
}

const actions = {
}

const getters = {
    getResidents: state => {
        const arr = []
        for (const key in state.residents) {
            const obj = state.residents[key]
            arr.push(obj)
        }
        return arr
    },
    getResidentById: state => id => {
        const obj = state.residents[id] ? state.residents[id] : null
        return obj
    }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

this should do the trick.

btw. avoid using arrays in state since it triggers a lot of getters if you remove or add an item to the array.

if you need an array on the view make a specific getter for it.